# How to conditionally import ES6 modules with rollup

Tags: es6-modules, rollupjs

I'm trying to conditionally import device-specific ES6 modules at run-time using Rollup and either Babel or Buble. I've seen similar questions but am still unclear if this is possible.

I've used Rollup since it's easy to generate UMD and ESM modules, then using the module/nomodule script pattern to ensure each device uses the appropriate module.

Is this possible yet with Rollup? Is there an alternative approach using a module loader that can determine whether to import ES5 or ES6 at run-time, or should I revert to Webpack?